# How to create string array from key/value in JS?

Tags: javascript, angular

trying to create string array from key/value below code returns key/value. How do I create string array?

main.js

```js
const array = [{
    "id": "123"
  },
  {
    "id": "124"
  }
]

console.log(Object.values(array));
const strinArray = [];

function convert() {
  for (const val of array) {
    strinArray.push(val);
  }
}
```

expected

```
["123","124"];
```

Comment: Your example should be a runnable snippet.  And it should log the result, not the input.

Answer (score 3):

You can use map to achieve the same.

```js
const array = [
  {"id":"123"},
  {"id":"124"}
]

console.log(array.map(item => item.id))
```

Comment: Took my upvote away when you mentioned IE11 and not using polyfills.  Mentioning such cases is not necessary and detracts from the answer, IMO.

Comment: Well, here you go then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method & destructuring for this:

```js
const array = [{ "id": "123" }, { "id": "124" } ]

console.log(array.map(({id}) => id))
```